# Is there any way I can do key combos on a steam controller (mac)

Tags: steam, macos, controllers

I would really like to be able to do combinations like ctrl+rightarrow and things like that. As a mac user knows, to switch between fullscreen apps (and use mission control), you need to use the trackpad, but there are also some keyboard combinations, including ctrl+rightarrow and ctrl+leftarrow. I have set up the controller so that the left back paddle is control and the joystick is the arrow keys. When i hold the button down and flick the joystick, nothing happens. help?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can activate multi-button then choose the buttons you want together
It will press all of them at the same time

Comment: Could you explain how to do it? The would greatly improve your answer.